# PHP MS Access ODBC driver seems not to be able process Access DLookUp() Function in SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

The problem is this.  When I create an SQL statement in PHP to be processed by an MS-Access ODBC driver, the query will not process properly if I include a DLookUp() function in the Access SQL Statement. I have had this problem occur with JOIN clauses as well, but not all JOIN clauses.

I am running a query to process an order where I am retrieving preferences requested by the user.  These preferences are also used for statements.  e.g., I might ask, "what is the captain's name?" and the end-user will enter the name in the provided text box.  Yet in the preferences area, I will also make simple statements that don't need an answer like "Flagrant Fouls will not be tolerated".

The entry screen looks like this:
[image: The User enters answers to questions and views any statements the recreation department might make]

When I want to display these answers made by the user later, I run the following query in php,

```
$sqlPrefs = "SELECT pq.QText, wr.The_Answer, wr.webtmporders_detail_ID" . 
  ", DLookUp('[IsStatement]','[tbl_Activities_Preference_Questions]','[PQ_ID]=' & [wr].[PQ_ID]) AS OnlyAStatement " .
  " FROM `tbl_Preference_Questions` pq" .
  " INNER JOIN `tblwebtmporders_detail_Requests` wr ON pq.PQ_ID = wr.PQ_ID" . 
  " WHERE wr.webtmporders_detail_ID =" .  $detID . 
  " ORDER BY wr.SortOrder";
          
$result_id_prefs = odbc_exec($connection_id, $sqlPrefs);
$numResults_prefs = odbc_record_count ($result_id_prefs, $connection_id, $sqlPrefs);
$results_prefs = all_odbc_rows($result_id_prefs);
        
if($numResults_prefs >0){
   $thePreferences = "<table border=\"0\" style=\"margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px\">";
   foreach ($results_prefs as $result_pref) 
   {
      $qtext = $result_pref['QText'];    
      if($result_pref['OnlyAStatement'] == true){
         $thePreferences .= "                   
<tr>
  <td class=\"prefs\" width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\">$qtext</td>
</tr>";                 
      }else{
         $thePreferences .= "                   
<tr>
  <td class=\"prefs\" width=\"50%\">$qtext</td>
  <td class=\"prefs\">" . $result_pref['The_Answer'] . "</td>
</tr>";
      }
   }
}
```

I have left out some calls to a logging function I have written that will show me what the $sqlPrefs variable resolves to:

```
SELECT pq.QText, wr.The_Answer, wr.webtmporders_detail_ID,
 DLookUp('[IsStatement]','[tbl_Activities_Preference_Questions]','[PQ_ID]=' & [wr].[PQ_ID]) AS OnlyAStatement  
FROM `tbl_Preference_Questions` pq 
INNER JOIN `tblwebtmporders_detail_Requests` wr ON pq.PQ_ID = wr.PQ_ID 
WHERE wr.webtmporders_detail_ID =76884 
ORDER BY wr.SortOrder
```

When I run this SQL statement with the Query Design Tool in MS Access, the query returns 9 records:
[image: The Query Returns 9 records when run in MS Access itself]

however, when the same query is run via the ODBC call shown in the PHP code above, it only returns only 1 record all with null values.

If I take the DLookup Call out of the query, then the query via ODBC will return 9 records.

This is the review screen when the DLookup() function is included in the ODBC sql statement.
[image: Review Screen when DLookup() is run thru ODBC call]

This is the screen when DLookup() is NOT included in the SQL statement run thru ODBC

[image: DLookUp() function not included in the ODBC SQL call]

What I am trying to do is fairly simple.  Notice the query results above.  the [OnlyAStatement] column is boolean.  If the item contains a statement only, and not a question and answer

```
if($result_pref['OnlyAStatement'] == true)
```

I want the statement to span across two columns, whereas if I am dealing with a Questions / Answer, I need two columns.  See the picture above with the yellow square.  I cannot determine if the sentence is a question / answer, or simply a statement, so i cannot manipulate the colspan attribute in the <td>  tag.

Does anyone have any idea why the DLookup() is not successfully run in the ODBC call but it is run when run withing the MS-Access program itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`DLookup()` is part of the Access Application object model ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dlookup)), not the database engine.
Therefore you can't use it via ODBC.

In your case it is easily avoided by adding a second JOIN to `tbl_Activities_Preference_Questions`.
Note that you'll need parentheses around all JOINs except the first one in Access SQL.

Comment: You are on target.  I did create the extra join.  However I still get a php warning when I include same named fields in the query, such as:
```
$sqlPrefs = "SELECT pq.PQ_ID, pq.QText, wr.The_Answer, wr.webtmporders_detail_ID, apq.isStatement
FROM (tbl_Preference_Questions AS pq INNER JOIN tblwebtmporders_detail_Requests AS wr ON pq.PQ_ID = wr.PQ_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Activities_Preference_Questions apq ON pq.PQ_ID = apq.PQ_ID
WHERE wr.webtmporders_detail_ID = $detID AND apq.ActivityID = $theActivityId
ORDER BY wr.SortOrder;";
```

Comment: the above triggers this error

this produces 
[24-Aug-2021 20:32:02 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  odbc_fetch_array(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The specified field '`PQ_ID`' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement., SQL state S1000 in SQLGetData

then it only returns one record.  PQ_ID exists in table [wr] and in table [pq].  the ODBC driver thinks the PQ_ID field is repetitive, but I have identified the table that I want to pull the [PQ_ID] field from.  This happens if I write pq.PQ_ID AS somevarname